# Convergence Warning in Early Stopping Algorithm Implementation

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am trying to understand the implementation of Early stopping from hands on ml 2, but I have the following error. The first being

```
The 'tol' parameter of SGDRegressor must be a float in the range [0, inf) or None. Got -inf instead.
```

hence I removed the tol value and leave it to the default state.

After that, it is basically giving series of the following.

```
usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/sklearn/linear_model/_stochastic_gradient.py:1548: ConvergenceWarning: Maximum number of iteration reached before convergence. Consider increasing max_iter to improve the fit.
  warnings.warn(
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/sklearn/linear_model/_stochastic_gradient.py:1548: ConvergenceWarning: Maximum number of iteration reached before convergence. Consider increasing max_iter to improve the fit.
  warnings.warn(
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/sklearn/linear_model/_stochastic_gradient.py:1548: ConvergenceWarning: Maximum number of iteration reached before convergence. Consider increasing max_iter to improve the fit.
  warnings.warn(
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/sklearn/linear_model/_stochastic_gradient.py:1548: ConvergenceWarning: Maximum number of iteration reached before convergence. Consider increasing max_iter to improve the fit.
  warnings.warn(
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/sklearn/linear_model/_stochastic_gradient.py:1548: ConvergenceWarning: Maximum number of iteration reached before convergence. Consider increasing max_iter to improve the fit.
  warnings.warn(
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/sklearn/linear_model/_stochastic_gradient.py:1548: ConvergenceWarning: Maximum number of iteration reached before convergence. Consider increasing max_iter to improve the fit.
  warnings.warn(
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/sklearn/linear_model/_stochastic_gradient.py:1548: ConvergenceWarning: Maximum number of iteration reached before convergence. Consider increasing max_iter to improve the fit.
  warnings.warn(
```

The code

```
np.random.seed()
m = 100
X = 20*np.random.randn(m, 1) - 10
y = 2 + X + 0.5 * X**2 + np.random.randn(m, 1)

X_train, X_val, y_train, y_val = train_test_split(X[:50], y[:50].ravel(), test_size=0.5, random_state=10)


poly_scaler = Pipeline([
    ("poly_features", PolynomialFeatures(degree=90, include_bias=False)),
    ("std_scaler", StandardScaler())
])

X_train_poly_scaled = poly_scaler.fit_transform(X_train)
X_val_poly_scaled = poly_scaler.transform(X_val)


sgd_reg = SGDRegressor(max_iter=1, warm_start=True,
                       penalty=None, learning_rate="constant", eta0=0.0005, random_state=42)


minimum_val_error = float("inf")

best_epoch = None
best_model = None 

for epoch in range(1000):
  sgd_reg.fit(X_train_poly_scaled, y_train)
  y_val_predict = sgd_reg.predict(X_val_poly_scaled)
  val_error = sgd_reg.predict(X_val_poly_scaled)
  if np.any(val_error < minimum_val_error):
    minimum_val_error = val_error 
    best_epoch = epoch
    best_model = deepcopy(sgd_reg)
```

I tried increasing the max_iter also, but to no use.